# md5 in http with range

Tags: http, http-headers, md5, range, md5sum

Imagine a user asks for `Rage: bytes=2-5` of a 10-byte file. What MD5 sum has to be served to the user? The MD5 sum of all 10 bytes or only of the partial content, bytes 2-5?

RFC2616 Section 14.15 reads:

> The MD5 digest is computed based on
>   the content of the entity-body,
>   including any content-coding that has
>   been applied, but not including any
>   transfer-encoding applied to the
>   message-body. If the message is
>   received with a transfer-encoding,
>   that encoding MUST be removed prior to
>   checking the Content-MD5 value against
>   the received entity.

How must I interpret that? I ask this because I would refrain from adding md5sums to partial content, iff it has to be re-generated for each range-request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/178.

So there is no easy answer, the Working Group will gladly accept feedback.

Comment: The ticket is about proxies combining multiple responses. But reading it, specifically the quote from RFC 3230, it's clear that Content-MD5 applies to the requested range only.

Comment: I agree with aaz, moreover though no http server that I've seen implements the content-md5 header correctly, and it's always the base64 encoded md5 sum of the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running HTTP over some very unusual network protocol, what are you gaining by using MD5 checksums? [TCP handles integrity checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer), the HTTP header is optional, and its not intended to ensure integrity against malicious attacks.

Comment: Even IPv6 does not have a checksum any more as TCP already has one.